# Instagram API with a link in the application

Tags: javascript, php, api, mobile, instagram

I created a personal website and I created a login button "ACCOUNT". This allows you to use the instagram API to retrieve basic information about the user who wants to create one. The API works fine, but when a new user wants to associate his Instagram account to my site from his smartphone (from the application instagram with a link to my site from my account [instagram.com/maximekahn_](https://instagram.com/maximekahn_)), it indicates an error of page loading.

Have you ever had this problem?

Do you have trouble loading the API page of my site from the Instagram app?

Does the loading error come from instagram or me?

Website: [maximekahn.com](https://maximekahn.com)

[PHP, HTML and Javascript have been used for development]

Thank you in advance for your answers!

```html
/*Instagram*/
    class Instagram
    {
        public function __construct ()
        {
            if(isset($_GET["code"]) && !empty($_GET["code"]))
            {
                $code = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_GET["code"]));
                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_id=[client_code]&client_secret=[secret_code]&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://maximekahn.com/api/instagram/&code=".$code);
                $curl = curl_exec($curl);
                $json = json_decode($curl);
                curl_close($curl);
                sleep(2);
                $firstname = explode(" ", $json->user->full_name)[0];
                $lastname = explode(" ", $json->user->full_name)[1];
                $array = array(
                    "id" => "NULL",
                    "user" => $json->user->id,
                    "firstname" => $firstname,
                    "lastname" => $lastname,
                    "name" => $json->user->username,
                    "biography" => $json->user->bio,
                    "email" => "",
                    "password" => "",
                    "image" => $json->user->profile_picture,
                    "birthday" => "1999-03-16",
                    "gender" => "",
                    "website" => $json->user->website,
                    "datetime" => "NOW()",
                );
                $arrayupdate = array(
                    "firstname" => $firstname,
                    "lastname" => $lastname,
                    "name" => $json->user->username,
                    "biography" => $json->user->bio,
                    "email" => "",
                    "password" => "",
                    "image" => $json->user->profile_picture,
                    "birthday" => "1999-03-16",
                    "gender" => "",
                    "website" => $json->user->website,
                    "datetime" => "NOW()",
                );  
                $criterion = array(
                    "user" => $json->user->id
                );
                $isset = array(
                    "name" => $json->user->username,
                );
                if($json->user->id){
                 $database = new database(); 
                    if($database->isset("maximekahn.accounts", $isset, "and") == true){
                        if($database->update("maximekahn.accounts", $arrayupdate, $criterion)){
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $json->user->id;
                            $_SESSION["name"] = $json->user->username;
                            $_SESSION["picture"] = $json->user->profile_picture;
                            $_SESSION["full"] = $json->user->full_name;
                            $_SESSION["biography"] = $json->user->bio;
                            $_SESSION["website"] = $json->user->website;
                            $_SESSION["business"] = $json->user->is_business;
                            $_SESSION["api/instagram"] = true;
                            header("Location: https://maximekahn.com");
                        }else{
                            $_SESSION["id"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["name"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["picture"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["fullname"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["biography"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["website"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["business"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["api/instagram"] = true;
                            header("Location: https://maximekahn.com");
                        }
                    }else{
                        if($database->add("maximekahn.accounts", $array)){
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $json->user->id;
                            $_SESSION["name"] = $json->user->username;
                            $_SESSION["picture"] = $json->user->profile_picture;
                            $_SESSION["full"] = $json->user->full_name;
                            $_SESSION["biography"] = $json->user->bio;
                            $_SESSION["website"] = $json->user->website;
                            $_SESSION["business"] = $json->user->is_business;
                            $_SESSION["api/instagram"] = true;
                            header("Location: https://maximekahn.com");
                        }else{
                            $_SESSION["id"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["name"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["picture"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["fullname"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["biography"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["website"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["business"] = "";
                            $_SESSION["api/instagram"] = true;
                            header("Location: https://maximekahn.com");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else if(!$_GET)
            {
                header("Location: https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[client_id]&redirect_uri=https://maximekahn.com/api/instagram/&response_type=code&scope=basic");
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: I add the code ↑